# Can Blazor Hybrid apps be cross-platform?

Tags: winforms, blazor, hybrid

I trying to find the most suitable Framework to port my legacy WinForms applications to the new technology. But the best way for me is cross-platform app.

I can build a Blazor Hybrid Windows Forms app. But can it be built as a cross-platform: for Windows, OSX, Linux ?

If no what can I use?

Comment: @If you really need native performance with web tech, go with MAUI Hybrid else go with Blazor server. If you don't need to mix web then just go with MAUI or Xamarin. Blazor wasm  is also a choice for intranet.

Comment: yes, but now MAUI is in preview. Also, I have asked about apps like this  can it be run in Linux? https://github.com/edandersen/blazor-desktop-crossplatform-sample

Comment: Then the answer you are looking for is Uno https://platform.uno/

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Blazor Hybrid apps can be cross-platform if the app is a .Net MAUI Blazor App.

[image: Creating a .Net MAUI Blazor App in Visual Studio]

The Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/maui?view=aspnetcore-6.0) shows how to create this type of app using Visual Studio 2022 (Preview edition at the time of writing in early June 2022).  The application is shown running as both a Windows desktop app and an Android app.

[image: Windows Hybrid Blazor app]

[image: Android Hybrid Blazor app]

You can see in the image above that Visual Studio says that the .Net MAUI Blazor App targets `macOS` as well as other platforms.  But, there does not seem to be support for Linux.  Further, the [MAUI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui) states that a Mac is required to build for `iOS` and `macOS`.

Answer (score 0):

Blazor Hybrid can be implemented in different containers, so you could have Uno Blazor Hybrid. There is already a COM+ Blazor Hybrid.

So - Yes. That's the point of it. Write once, run everywhere (assuming a shared Razor library).